# Wilcoxon test - which is difference and applicability of signed-rank and rank-sum?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I don't have a strong background in statistics, I am reading two papers which mention Wilcoxon tests, signed-rank and rank-sum, and they are applied on two different situations.

I found a bit cumbersome to understand what they do, and how to chose between them for appropriate significance testing.

Could you please understand these three steps, based on the assumptions of the tests ?

- https://www.statisticssolutions.com/free-resources/directory-of-statistical-analyses/assumptions-of-the-wilcox-sign-test/
- https://data.library.virginia.edu/the-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test/

--

1. One paper uses signed-rank to test if there is a true difference between two machine learning classifiers.
   The researcher applies the test to the pairs of scores (f1-scores) of the two classifiers, for each K-fold in a cross-fold validation.

As far as I understand, like this:

```
for each K-fold:
   compute f1-score for A
   compute f1-score for B
   compute signed-rank for (A, B)
```

In this example, I would like to understand:

- why a statistical testing of this kind is necessary or useful, to appreciate that a machine learning model is consistently better then another one ?
- Why comparing the metrics is not enough, and how the signed-rank address the issue?

2. One paper uses rank-sum test, to test if sequences in syllables of animals follows the same distributions. But unfortunately, it does explain what is the actual input.

For my purpose, I would like to replicate the result, but unsure what to pass as input and which test chose.

Consider the situation I have one animal emitting sequences of sounds, in two different contexts. The two context are independent, that is an assumption for rank-sum. But the emitter is the same, so I could consider the sequences are dependent.

- Am I misunderstanding meaning of independence / dependence?
- What kind of input could I use to compare sequences of syllables, according the the assumptions of the tests : shall frequencies of syllables be representative value, to test that order of syllables in sequences is drawn from similar distributions ?